# Read only fields for interviewing

Tags: wordpress, civicampaign, civisurvey

I'm setting up a walklist for volunteers to interview people through civicampaign/civisurvey. While they are conducting interviews, I'd like it so that there is a read only field, address, that is listed. I made it a custom profile that includes address as a read only field, but when conducting a survey, only some addresses are read only, but others are editable. I'm unsure why some are read only and some aren't. Can anyone give some advice? Thanks!

Comment: can you share a screenshot of your profile address field configuration and the display of profile ?

Comment: @jitendra-fuzion see my answer below. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the issue. The reason that some of them were read only and some weren't was due to a bad import. It seems like the Contacts that were having those issues, had more than 1 empty Supplementary Addresses. There would be 1 Main Address with it geocoded and filled in, but there would be like 4 empty address entries. Removing all the invalid supplementary addresses fixed the issue. Not too sure why those addresses would mess up the results but hey, at least it got fixed!